# Prediction of Pure Premium with offset

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, predictive-models, offset, tweedie-distribution

I'm modeling a pure premium with glm and using an offset term equal to log(exposure).
My question is, in R, what does `predict.glm(fit, train, type="response")` return?
-The cost amount? and in this case i have to divide with exposure to get the predicted Pure Premium

- Or the Pure Premium by supposing the exposure is already taken in the prediction?

Comment: What kind of glm are you referring to? The option `type="response" will make predict to deliver a prediction on the response scale, i.e. a binary variable if it's a logistic regression, etc.

Comment: thanks you for your response @utobi. No it's not a logistic regression. I'm modeling a Pure Premium in insurance and the variable is the cost of loss (continuous variable).
the model  in R is glm(cost loss ~X+log(exposure), family=tweedie(var.power=1.41, link.power=0)

Comment: "using an offset term equal to log(exposition)"  ... you mean log(exposure) there, right?

Comment: yes i mean log(exposure) @Glen_b

Comment: Curious then that once the error was pointed out you did not choose to correct it in the post. I have now done so.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, in R, what does `predict.glm(fit, train, type="response")` return?
> -The cost amount?

If you uses as fit the function

```
glm(cost loss ~X+log(exposure), family=tweedie(var.power=1.41, link.power=0)
```

then the prediction is for `cost loss` which is your response variable in the model.

> i have to divide with exposure to get the predicted Pure Premium

This depends on what 'Pure Premium' means. It is not a typical statistics term, so it might help to define this in the question.

Comment: Loss cost, also known as pure premium or pure cost, is the amount of money an insurer must pay to cover claims. Its equal to loss cost/exposure. So the glm model is written as 
E(Y)=Xb + log(exposure).